# Cant show name of logged-in user - angular2 -meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, angular

I just want to show the name of the current logged in user, but I cant make it works.

I wrote this on the `app.component`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import template from './app.component.html';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';
import {LoginButtons} from 'angular2-meteor-accounts-ui';
//import our Carousel Component
import {CSSCarouselComponent} from './imports/componenets/carousel/carousel.component';
import { InjectUser } from 'angular2-meteor-accounts-ui';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, LoginButtons,CSSCarouselComponent]
})
@InjectUser('user')
export class AppComponent {
    user: Meteor.User;
    constructor() {
        console.log(this.user);
    }
    loginFacebook(event) {
        Meteor.loginWithFacebook({}, function(err){
            if (err) {
                throw new Meteor.Error("Facebook login failed");
            }
            console.log(Meteor.user().profile.name;);
        });
    }
}
```

`console.log(this.user);` returns `undefined`.

`console.log(Meteor.user().profile.name;);` works and gives me the name, but I have no success to export it to the html and show that.

Comment: I have more or less the same problem. Only solution for me is at the moment, to copy the user to another variable: `let user = Meteor.user()`. Then I can use `{{user.username}}` in the html code.

If you have found another solution please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference *Meteor* in your Component, for example as `let M = Meteor;`. Then you can use `{{M.user().profile.name}}` in your html.

Also `this.user` is never set in your code, you just define its class. Anyway, you should always use `Meteor.user()` or `M.user()`, because it's always up-to-date.